Find the condition number of a normal matrices.
Find the condition number of a normal matrices.
My attempt:-
I know condition number of $X\in \mathbb C^{n,n}$ is defined by $\kappa(X)=||X|| \cdot ||X^{-1}||.$ Definition of Normal matrix is given by $X^HX=XX^H.$
We know that $1=||X X^{-1}||\leq ||X|| ||X^{-1}||$ for all consistent norms$^{[\text{Page 5}]}$. Can we prove $||X|| ||X^{-1}||\leq 1$?

What if $X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\ 2& 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is the 2-norm?

You know that $||X|| ||X^{-1}||\geq1$ so that if $||X|| ||X^{-1}||\leq1$ you will have shown that $||X|| ||X^{-1}||=1$. A simple $2\times 2$ example will show you that this can't be the case.

As some normal matrices are singular, the condition numbers of normal matrices are not bounded above.

okay. thanks for the comments

What if $X$ is unitary?

With the spectral norm, the condition number of normal matrices is always $\sigma_{max}(X)/\sigma_{min}(X)$
